# Question incorrectly closed as duplicate - flagging of no help

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495972/getting-a-smooth-transition-effect-in-css-when-toggling-from-a-visually-hidden-e) on Stack Overflow recently and it incorrectly got closed as a duplicate.

The "duplicate" question it was linked to was asking about "Transitions on the display: property" - which doesn't apply to my use case; I already have a solution to transition out of a display none state.

I have voted to reopen, flagged for moderator attention (with no action) and have just now edited the question to clarify it further.

I'm not sure what else I can do to get it reopened?

I really do think people on SO are too trigger happy when it comes to flagging questions as duplicates without actually reading the question and the apparent duplicate(s).

Comment: `I really do think people on SO are too trigger happy when it comes to flagging questions as duplicates`. Totally agree. I've had this happen many times. If the person doing the flagging actually spent some time reading the question, they would understand its not the same.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvotes?

Comment: I've reopened it with my Mjolnir powers. You should be aware though that the duplicate may have had answers to your question and **that** may have been the reason for the dupehammer

Comment: One final point... You seem to be asking for an improvement in working code. That's not really suitable for SO. Perhaps Code Review would be more appropriate, but check their guidelines first.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks very much!

Comment: @gnat lol yes I seen that - that is why I explained what I had done in this question to show I had done the measures pointed out in that answer.